# PHP - удаление пробелов в начале строки больших текстов, написанных в <textarea></textarea>

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть следующая textarea, в которую можно писать многостроковый код.

[image]

Моя задача, адекватно резать пробелы (которые показаны на скриншоте), только перед началом строки. trim() не подходит ввиду того, что режет пробел только на первой строке, а остальные игнорирует. А удаление множественных пробелов так же не подойдет ввиду, что нужно удалять и одиночные. Нет абсолютно никаких идей, как это сделать, даже регулярками, ибо не понимаю, почему последующие строки не режутся тримом.

Есть идеи?

Comment: Скорее всего, остальные строки игнорирует не trim(), а код, который от нас скрывают.

Comment: И как это обойти?

Answer (score 3):

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) не удаляет, потому что и не должен. Для него все, что находится в textarea, - одна большая строка. Согласно документации, trim удаляет пробелы в начале и в конце строки, это вы и наблюдаете.

Думаю, вы ищете что-то наподобие этого:

```
$txt = "     asd  
  asdasd  
     asasdas     
asd     
aasda
   asdasd
";

$pattern = '/\n[\s]+/i';
$replacement = "\n";

$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $txt);
$txt = trim($txt);

echo $txt;
```

Результат:

```
asd
asdasd
asasdas
asd
aasda
asdasd
```

Обратите внимание, что пробелы в конце строки остались, но вы так вроде и хотели.

Второй вариант - это делать [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) по символу новой строки. Получите массив, где каждый элемент - каждая новая строка из вашего textarea. Строки можно будет обработать и склеить обратно.